# How do I use the results from one query as a nested input for a larger query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a task to check a long script for 65 specific steps that ran during the day but the process is one by one right now.
Using a key_name, I used this to find the Unique_Key needed for the next part. So I run this and then copy the unique_key.

```
select top 2 UNIQUE_KEY, START_TIME from Table_Stats s
where key_name like '%V:News%'
and key_id = '148'
order by START_TIME desc
```

The unique_key from above was used with:

```
select CAST(AVG(CAST(START_TIME as float)) as DATETIME) FROM Table_Stats s
where key_name like '%V:News%'
and UNIQUE_KEY = '00099212434324584535'
```

I want to be able to grab the Unique_key from the top 2 of each key_id (they should match) and then output average the start_time associated with each unique_key and tied back to the original key_id.

If I can just get these as one step and input the key_id once to output the avg time that would be great. Even better would be if i could enter in an array of key_ids and get all the avg times back.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in` or `join`:

```
select CAST(AVG(CAST(START_TIME as float)) as DATETIME) FROM Table_Stats s
where key_name like '%V:News%'
and UNIQUE_KEY = (select top 2 UNIQUE_KEY 
                  from Table_Stats s
                  where key_name like '%V:News%' and key_id = '148'
                  order by START_TIME desc
                 );
```